# jQuery slideUp to show the element and not hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery's slideUp effect hides the element by sliding it up, while slideDown shows the element. I want to show my div using slideUp. can anyone guide me ? thanks

Answer (score 54):

```
$("div").click(function () {
      $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

Comment: Umair, I have not tried this, but you could try to change the "hide" to "show" and change the direction to which ever direction you want.

Comment: Should not be so hard to find out the opposite `show()` if you don't want to hide it.

Comment: these arguments are not even documented. dont work at all, even the same code using hide

Comment: This is documented, just follow the link provided by Jason, Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/AGtG8/

Comment: You'll need to include jquerUI too, did you?

Comment: no I didnt, I dont want jQuery UI. I want to do this with jQuery only!

Comment: If you want it, do it. There was an answer before(has been deleted now) using animate, that should be the right way. But you have to do something more on your own than only tell us what you want to have.

Answer (score 15):

It's a little more complex than just saying `slideUpShow()` or something, but you can still do it. This is a pretty simple example, so you might find some edge-cases that need adressing.

```
$("#show-animate-up").on("click", function () {
    var div = $("div:not(:visible)");

    var height = div.css({
        display: "block"
    }).height();

    div.css({
        overflow: "hidden",
        marginTop: height,
        height: 0
    }).animate({
        marginTop: 0,
        height: height
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).css({
            display: "",
            overflow: "",
            height: "",
            marginTop: ""
        });
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle showing the `slideUp`/`slideDown` methods, the same effects using `animate`, and a modified version using `animate` that goes in reverse: http://jsfiddle.net/sd7zsyhe/1/

Since `animate` is a built-in jQuery function, you don't need to include jQuery UI.

Comment: +1 This works very well and you have a great jsfiddle example. I don't know why this hasn't been chosen as the correct answer

Comment: This should be the answer if the OP doesn't want to use the jQuery UI library

Answer (score 7):

To get the opposite of slideUp and slideDown. Add these two functions to jQuery.

```js
$.fn.riseUp = function()   { $(this).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000); }
$.fn.riseDown = function() { $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000); }
```

Comment: For this you need to use the jQueryUI library, [link](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery)

Comment: This is effectively the same answer that @jason gave earlier only somewhat more obtuse due to namespacing.

Comment: It is essentially the same answer, though this in shortcut-form, that may be more readable to some.

Comment: This is a much better answer because it is easily re-usable.

Comment: may be you want try `slideToggle()` it's up and down show hide functionality. Slow down the movement by give it a value like this `slideToggle(500)` or `slideToggle('slow')`.

Answer (score 5):

I found a tricky way...
you can set div with css style bottom:0px, 
add call 
`$("#div).slideDown();` 

will show with the slideUp-to-show effect you want.

Comment: This works, but only as long as the #div in question can also be set to position: absolute; When the #div in question needs to be positioned relative, it does not.

Answer (score 3):

[Jquery toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

This toggle effect is only for up and down. Jquery UI is for every other direction

Comment: how to use toggle for up and down ?

Answer (score 2):

Despite the name, slideDown can actually slide your element both ways. Use absolute position if it is required to animate inside the parent element:

```css
#slideup {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  background:#0243c9;
  color:#fafefa;
  width:100%;
  display:none;
  padding: 20px;
}
#littleslideup {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  display:none;
  padding:10px;
  z-index:100;
}
#slidedown {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  background:#c94333;
  color:#fafefa;
  width:100%;
  display:none;
  padding: 20px;
}
button {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:16px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="position:relative">This amounts to 70% of the total timber stand area of the region (not including the dwarf pine and shrubby alder) and is more than the total area of all other stone birch forests growing in the Magadan, Khabarovsk, Primorye and Sakhalin regions and other areas of its distribution.
  <div id="littleslideup">Absolute-positioned element</div>
</div>

<span style="color:red">Click >> </span>

<button onclick="jQuery('#slideup').slideDown(1500);"      >"Slideup"</button>
<button onclick="jQuery('#slidedown').slideDown(1500);"    >"Slidedown"</button>
<button onclick="jQuery('#littleslideup').slideDown(1500);">"Slideup" inside element</button>

<div>Finally, closing the subject of volcanic activity, it must be said that the stone birch stands by its functional reaction quite adequately in order to re ect the character and intensity of the physical, chemical and thermic processes, stipulated by volcanism as well as the in uence upon biota and ecosystems.</div> 

<div id="slideup">Could be a bottom cookie warning bar</div>

<div id="slidedown">Could be a top cookie warning bar</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who don´t use the Jquery UI but want to add the function to Jquery Library:

```
jQuery.fn.slideUpShow = function (time,callback) {
    if (!time)
        time = 200;
    var o = $(this[0]) // It's your element

    if (o.is(':hidden'))
    {
        var height = o.css({
            display: "block"
        }).height();

        o.css({
            overflow: "hidden",
            marginTop: height,
            height: 0
        }).animate({
            marginTop: 0,
            height: height
        }, time, function () {
            $(this).css({
                display: "",
                overflow: "",
                height: "",
                marginTop: ""
            });
            if (callback)
                callback();
        });
    }

    return this; // This is needed so others can keep chaining off of this
};

jQuery.fn.slideDownHide = function (time,callback) {
    if (!time)
        time = 200;
    var o = $(this[0]) // It's your element
    if (o.is(':visible')) {
        var height = o.height();

        o.css({
            overflow: "hidden",
            marginTop: 0,
            height: height
        }).animate({
            marginTop: height,
            height: 0
        }, time, function () {
            $(this).css({
                display: "none",
                overflow: "",
                height: "",
                marginTop: ""
            });
            if (callback)
                callback();
        });
    }

    return this;
}
```

**Credits: @redbmk answer**

Answer (score 0):

*I've got some downvotes so I checked my answer and indeed I didn't answered correctly the OP question, sorry. So I'm gonna try to fix that.*

First, the `slideUp()` method in JQuery is intended to hide the element rather than reveal it. It is basically the opposite of `slideDown()` which shows your element by sliding it down.

By knowing that I think we agree that there is no magic function right there to do a slide up effect to show an element (in JQuery).

So we need to do a little bit of work to get what we need: slid up reveal effect. I found out some solutions and here is one I think simple to implement:

https://coderwall.com/p/9dsvia/jquery-slideup-to-reveal

The solution above works with the hover event, for the click event try this modified code:

http://jsfiddle.net/D7uT9/250/

The answer given by [@redbmk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29291705/2931699) is also a working solution.

Sorry for my misunderstanding the first time.

---

**OLD ANSWER**

It's an old post, but if someone is looking for a solution here is my recommandation.

We can, now, use `slideToggle()` to achieve this effect (without the need of jQuery UI).

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
      $("div").slideToggle();
});
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Comment: It would be very useful if the downvoting is accompanied by a comment. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Having encountered this with a student looking to "slide up always hide" an error container, I advised he simply use CSS transitions:

```css
.slide-up {
  transition: 1s ease-out;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.slide-up[aria-hidden="true"] {
  transform: scale(0);
  height: 0;
}
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  const $submitButton = $(".btn");
  const $someDivs = $("div");
  const $animatedSlidingTargets = $(".slide-up");
  $someDivs.on("click", function() {
    $animatedSlidingTargets.attr("aria-hidden", true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For @Jason's answer, whether slide-up to show and slide-down to hide, you still need to use the `{ direction: "down" }` option in jQuery:

```
$(".btnAbout").on("click", function () {
    // Slide-up to show
    $("#divFooter").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});

$("#btnCloseFooter").on("click", function () {
    // Slide-down to hide
    $("#divFooter").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
```

But this requires `jquery-ui`, or else you'll hit the `TypeError: something.easing[this.easing] is not a function` error:

```
<script defer src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```