# jQuery slideUp show element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a div slide out upwards using `jQuery.slideUp()`, however it seems like that is only for hiding an element, while `.slideDown()` is for showing an element. I'm looking at [the W3 Docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp) and there is no mention of if this is possible.

Does anybody know how I can make a div slide up and be shown?

Comment: There's nothing built in to do what you want. `slideUp()` hides the element by essentially decreasing the height till 0 and then `display: none;`. You'll need to write something custom to reveal an item upwards.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242780/jquery-slideup-to-show-the-element-and-not-hide)

Answer (score 1):

`.slideUp()`, `.slideDown()`, and `.slideToggle()` are indeed for hiding/showing divs with a sliding transition. Have a look here: http://api.jquery.com/slideup/

If you want to move a displayed div around the page, I'm afraid there's nothing built-in to accomplish that, however it's relatively straight-forward to write an animate function.  Have a look at the [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [w3school article](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).